# How can I remove an existing topCalc?

Tags: tabulator

Once a column definition has had a topCalc applied, I don't seem to be able to get rid of it. The formatter is removed, but the calculated numbers remain. I tried several ways of clearing it out, but no luck. Below is the most recent attempt.  This works fine if is_group is true on the first run. However, once is_group has been false and the topCalcs applied, subsequent runs where is_group is true still have them. I have confirmed that the topCalc properties are being removed from the column definition objects.
Using Tabulator Version 4.9.3.

```
                            autoColumns:true,
                            autoColumnsDefinitions:function(definitions) {
                                let is_group = false;
                                if(document.getElementById("cex-item-detail").value == 1) {is_group = true;};
                                definitions.forEach((column) => {
                                    if(column.field == "fpath") {
                                        column.title = "Item";
                                        column.visible = true;
                                        column.headerFilter = true;
                                        column.width = 600;
                                    } else {
                                        if(column.field == "cost") {
                                            column.title = "Total Cost";
                                        } else {
                                            column.title = column.field.toUpperCase();
                                        }
                                        column.hozAlign = "right";
                                        column.headerHozAlign = "right";
                                        column.formatter = "money";
                                        column.formatterParams = {precision: 0};
                                        if(!is_group) {
                                            column.topCalc = "sum";
                                            column.topCalcFormatter = "money";
                                            column.topCalcFormatterParams = {precision: 0};
                                        } else {
                                            delete column.topCalc;
                                            delete column.topCalcFormatter;
                                            delete column.topCalcFormatterParams;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                return(definitions);
                            }
```

Comment: Instead of `delete column.topCalc;`, try `column.topCalc = false`

Comment: @Tim: Nope, same problem. I have also tried column.topCalc = "".

Comment: Would you be able to provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Tim: Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dc68wvn/1/).  Once you select WIth topCalc, they will never go away.

Comment: Hi @EMF, looks like Tabulator doesn't remove the calculations row once it is created simply by changing the column definitions. Which is a missing feature IMO.  However, looking at the Tabulator code, I see that setting `groupBy` option to an empty array would trigger the removal of the calculations.  So, as a hack, if you don't ever plan on grouping your data, you can call `table.setGroupBy([])` before calling `table.setData` on your dropdown change event to get the result you want.  Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ak863wb9/)

Comment: @Tim: It's kludgy but it works. Thanks!